# Rails Form Association Automatically New

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, associations

I have a rails form for movies. In this form is Title and Trailer_id (which has the youtube url)

Trailer_id is an association with the trailers scaffold.

So when I go to /trailers/new and add a new youtube url, I can then see it in a dropdown on my movies/new.

But how do I automatically create a new trailer when entered in the movies form

So instead of having me go to trailers/new and create a new trailer 
How do I create it directly from the Movies form

Answer (score 0):

You can use the nested_form gem.

Add this to your `gemfile`

```
gem "nested_form"
```

Run `bundle`

Add this to your application.js

```
//= require jquery_nested_form
```

Add this in `movie.rb`

```
has_many :trailers
accepts_nested_attributes_for :trailers
```

And in your form view:

```
<%= nested_form_for @movie do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :trailers do |trailer_form| %>
    <%= trailer_form.text_field :link %>
    <%= trailer_form.link_to_remove "Remove this trailer" %>
  <% end %>
  <p><%= f.link_to_add "Add a trailer", :trailers %></p>
<% end %>
```

You can see more details on https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form